# Populating ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to populate an array list, however, my array list constantly equals 0, and never initializes, despite my declaring it over main().

This is my code.

```
static ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>(10); //The parenthesis value changes the size of the array.
static Random randomize = new Random(); //This means do not pass 100 elements.

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    int tally = 0;
    int randInt = 0;

    randInt = randomize.nextInt(100); //Now set the random value.
    System.out.println(randInt); //Made when randomizing number didn't work.
    System.out.println(array.size() + " : Array size");

    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
    {
        randInt = randomize.nextInt(100); //Now set the random value.
        array.add(randInt);
        tally = tally + array.get(i); //add element to the total in the array.
    }       
    //System.out.println(tally);
}
```

Can someone tell me what is going on? I feel rather silly, I've done ArrayLists for my default arrays and I cannot figure this out to save my life!

Comment: "my array list constantly equals 0" you mean the elements are all zero? the number of elements is zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new ArrayList<Integer>(10)` creates an `ArrayList` with *initial capacity* of 10 but the size is still 0 as there are no elements in it.

`ArrayList` is backed by an array underneath so it does create an array of a given size (initial capacity) when constructing the object so it doesn't need to resize it every time you insert a new entry (arrays in Java are **not** dynamic so when you want to insert a new record and the array is full you need to create a new one and move all the items, that's an expensive operation) but even though the array is created ahead of time `size()` will return `0` until you actually `add()` something to the list.

That's why this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
 // ...
}
```

Will not execute as `array.size()` is `0`.

Change it to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

And it should work.